# When i pressed Enter in keyboard it submits the form without going through the javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

When i Pressed Enter/Return in Keyboard it submits the form without going through my javascript function in the Submit button of the Form.

I'm thinking of manipulating the keyboard command when pressed but i think that would take time.

so, is there any short way of doing so? like an event in the form/button?

Any Answer will help.
Thank you.

PS: sorry for bad explanation.

Comment: and where is HTML / java script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming "your JavaScript function" is assigned to the submit button's `click` handler, it's obvious why it didn't work: you didn't click the submit button. The code to handle a form submission should go onto the form's `submit` handler. It will trigger from both submit buttons and Enter key.

One more critical piece of info: your handler has to return `false`, or call `preventDefault` on the event; if you don't, the form will still submit after your code exits.

Comment: return false; doesn't work.`function submitControl(){
 dlemployee_cert();
 return false;
}`

Comment: Then you messed up something else, and I'm not psychic. See the most upvoted comment on this page, by @MishaTs. Also, "doesn't work" is the worst possible description of the problem. Did you try all three of my suggestions, or just the `return false`? In which specific way doesn't it work? Do you get an error message? Do you still get a submit anyway? Did you try putting an `alert("test")` at the top of your function to see if it is at all entered? EDIT: Where's the HTML which calls your function, or the JS which binds the event?

Comment: I transferred the function to the form 'onSubmit' event. i know what i have done wrong, i forgot to return function(); in the event. sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation:

- http://api.jquery.com/submit/

You can do something like this:

HTML

```
<form id="form" action="process.htm">   
    <input id="name" type="text" value="Joe" />
    <input type="submit" value="Say hi" />
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
   alert('Hi there, ' + $('#name').val());

   // If you uncomment the below, it will submit
   return false; // Prevent submit
});
```

The `return false` will prevent it from submitting after your JavaScript submit function finishes, if desired.

Live example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/58hfn/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a handler to the **form** onsubmit-

```
<form name="forma" onsubmit="validate()"
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your javascript function contains some errors. To see if there are some javascript errors view the Chrome Console Ctrl+Shift+i